# Fonts used in scrrprt TOC

Tags: fonts, koma-script

in a scrrprt document I'm using proportional old style numbers throughout, but I want to use monospace lining numbers for the pages in the TOC.

I can use the `chapterentrypagenumber` font for the top level, but `sectionentrypagenumber` is only available for article (because it's the top level there).
Which font is in use for the rest of the numbers?

Here's a simple test document — how do I change font for the black numbers?

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setkomafont{chapterentrypagenumber}{\color{red}}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\color{teal}}
\begin{document}
{\color{blue}\tableofcontents}
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also is there a simple debugging switch one could use for these things, to just put the name of the komafont in use into the document?
I tried

```
\renewcommand{\usekomafont}[2]{(#1:#2)}
```

But there are clearly some font changes happening that I'm not catching:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Use the tocstyle package from the KOMA bundle and the pagenumberhook:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xcolor, tocstyle}
\setkomafont{chapterentrypagenumber}{\color{red}}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\color{teal}}
\settocstylefeature{pagenumberhook}{\sffamily{}}
\begin{document}
{\color{blue}\tableofcontents}
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\end{document}
```

I used `\sffamily` as font command, but maybe you'd like to have something else.

---

EDIT

It is a rainy day, I longed for something coloured and so I played around with this, just to find out which level of nonsense KOMAscript sustains:

```
\documentclass[x11names]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xcolor, blindtext}
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{KOMAlike}

\addtokomafont{chapterentrypagenumber}{\color{purple}}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\color{purple}}

\addtokomafont{chapterentry}{\Large\color{purple}}
%\addtokomafont{disposition}{\color{Snow4}}
\settocstylefeature{entryhook}{\color{Wheat4!70!black}\bfseries}
 \settocstylefeature{pagenumberhook}{\rlap{\color{Wheat1}\hspace{-0.3em}\rule[-0.6ex]{0.6em}{2.5ex}\color{Wheat3}\rule[0.1ex]{0.6em}{2.5ex}}\bfseries\sffamily\color{teal}}

\begin{document}
 \tableofcontents
% \chapter{Chapter}
% \section{Section}
% \subsection{Subsection}

\blinddocument

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

And you get such a cute TOC:
[image: contents-coloured]

Comment: Yes that's what I ended up with, but I'd still like to know what KOMAscript does to the non-chapter page numbers

Comment: KOMA-script consists of tens of thousands (can you say that in English?) of lines of code. Even if I could explain it, you'd need to know a lot about TeX, LaTeX and KOMA-script. And if you knew this -- well, then you could find out yourself!

Comment: @pascal: KOMA does nothing to the page numbers. By default is uses the standard `\@dottedtocline` to print the toc-lines, which in turn uses `\normalfont \normalcolor` to print the number. The fact that a hook has been added to one level doesn't mean that it exists for every level - KOMA isn't always really consequent (but it naturally can change in the future ...).

Comment: Ah, ok I expected it to use a komafont there instead of `\normalfont` directly, thanks! (the problem with KOMAscript is that it's not only massive and full of indirections, the internal parts are still documented mostly in german, but I'm not sure if that necessarily makes it harder to understand at that point)

Comment: Oh, this is so beautifully and ugly ;-) +1

Comment: very nice, but it does not work when i use `hypersetup` to set `linkcolor`, the `linkcolor` will override the color of chapter in TOC

Comment: @scmg Then please ask a new question with an MWE...

Comment: Since KOMA -Script 3.31 the package has been removed from
KOMA -Script. It is deprecated and should not be used any
longer. (The Obsolete Package tocstyle)