# Uppercase, italics and hyperlinks in toc of scrartcl without using tocstyle

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, tocstyle

The table of contents in my document looks like this at the moment:
[image]

This is exactly how it should look like (with hyperlinks) - there is one problem, though. I only got this restult by using the `tocstyle` package, which I would now like to change. Instead, I'd like to have the same result using the `tocloft` package, if possible. Here is the code I've used up to now, so this one still contains `tocstyle`:

```
\documentclass[headings=normal, oneside, hidelinks]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tocstyle}  
\usetocstyle{allwithdot} 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4} 

%% Distances between number and entry
\settocfeature[toc][1]{spaceafternumber}{15pt}
\settocfeature[toc][2]{spaceafternumber}{15pt}
\settocfeature[toc][3]{spaceafternumber}{12pt}
\settocfeature[toc][4]{spaceafternumber}{12pt}

%% Formatting entries
\usepackage{microtype}
\settocfeature[toc][1]{entryhook}{\MakeHyperLinkStartUppercase\bfseries} 
\settocfeature[toc][2]{entryhook}{\MakeHyperLinkStartUppercase}
\settocfeature[toc][3]{entryhook}{\itshape} 
\settocfeature[toc][4]{entryhook}{}

%% Entries with uppercase and hyperlinks
\makeatletter 
\newcommand*\MakeHyperLinkStartUppercase{% 
\let\saved@hyper@linkstart\hyper@linkstart 
\def\hyper@linkstart##1##2##3{% 
    \saved@hyper@linkstart{##1}{##2}{\textls[50]{\MakeUppercase {##3}}}}% 
} 
\makeatother 

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document} 
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{Eins}
\section{Zwei}
\subsection{Zwei}
\section{Drei}
\subsection{Drei}
\subsubsection{Drei}
\section{Vier}
\subsection{Vier}
\subsubsection{Vier}
\paragraph{Vier}
\end{document}
```

I've been looking for an alternative solution for a long time, but most suggestions contained the memoir class. However, I was able to use something from this answer here ([How to make section name uppercase in ToC?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156916/how-to-make-section-name-uppercase-in-toc)). Here is how far I've gotten, trying to use `tocloft`:

```
 \documentclass[headings=normal, oneside, hidelinks]{scrartcl}

 \usepackage{tocloft}
 \usepackage{textcase}
 \setcounter{tocdepth}{4} 
 \setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

 %% Distances between dots
 \makeatletter
 \renewcommand*{\@dotsep}{0.5}
 \makeatother

 %% Distances between number and entry
 \makeatletter
 \renewcommand{\l@section}{\vspace{.025\textwidth} \@dottedtocline{1}{20pt}{20pt}}
 \renewcommand{\l@subsection}{\@dottedtocline{2}{40pt}{30pt}}
 \renewcommand{\l@subsubsection}{\@dottedtocline{3}{70pt}{40pt}}
 \renewcommand{\l@paragraph}{\@dottedtocline{4}{110pt}{40pt}}

 \usepackage{hyperref} 

 %% Uppercase and hyperref for sections
 \makeatletter
 \let\oldcontentsline\contentsline
 \def\contentsline#1#2{%
\expandafter\ifx\csname l@#1\endcsname\l@section
\expandafter\@firstoftwo
\else
\expandafter\@secondoftwo
\fi
{%
    \oldcontentsline{#1}{\bfseries\MakeTextUppercase{#2}}%
}{%
\oldcontentsline{#1}{#2}%
 }%
 }
 \makeatother


 \begin{document} 
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{Eins}
\section{Zwei}
\subsection{Zwei}
\section{Drei}
\subsection{Drei}
\subsubsection{Drei}
\section{Vier}
\subsection{Vier}
\subsubsection{Vier}
\paragraph{Vier}
 \end{document}
```

So basically I still need the subsections to be in uppercase and the subsubsections should be in italics ... Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: A "quick and dirty" solution would be to 'hack' short titles and define layout just for ToC entries (cf. e.g. [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6866/64454))

Comment: you can use `\setkomafont`. see here for help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241210/fonts-used-in-scrrprt-toc

Comment: If possible I'd prefer a not-so-dirty solution ... Though, thanks for your answer! As for the second suggestion: I tried to give `setkomafont` the arguments `\MakeUppercase`, `\MakeTextUppercase` and `\MakeHyperLinkStartUppercase` but none of these worked ... (also, I'd like to avoid the `tocstyle` package)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the usage of `tocloft` together with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended.

With the next KOMA-Script version 3.20 there is no additional package needed to get the desired result. You can get a pre-release version from the KOMA-Script website: [Using most current KOMA-Script with TeX Live, MacTeX or MiKTeX](http://www.komascript.de/node/1801)

```
\documentclass[headings=normal, hidelinks]{scrartcl}[2016/03/16]
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4} 

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocnumsep=15pt,
  toclinefill=\TOCLineLeaderFill,
  tocpagenumberformat=\normalfont
]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocnumsep=15pt]{subsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocentryformat=\itshape,tocnumsep=12pt]{subsubsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocnumsep=12pt]{paragraph}

\renewcommand\addsectiontocentry[2]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{section}{#1}{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#2}}{#2}}%
}
\renewcommand\addsubsectiontocentry[2]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{subsection}{#1}{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#2}}{#2}}%
}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document} 
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{Eins}
\section{Zwei}
\subsection{Zwei}
\section{Drei}
\subsection{Drei}
\subsubsection{Drei}
\section{Vier}
\subsection{Vier}
\subsubsection{Vier}
\paragraph{Vier}
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

With KOMA-Script version 3.19a (current on CTAN) or older I would really recommend to use `tocstyle`. Both `tocstyle` and the KOMA-Script classes have the same author. The warning because of the alpha version can be ignored.

```
\documentclass[headings=normal, oneside, hidelinks]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text

\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{allwithdot} 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4} 

%Distances between number and entry
\settocfeature[toc][1]{spaceafternumber}{15pt}
\settocfeature[toc][2]{spaceafternumber}{15pt}
\settocfeature[toc][3]{spaceafternumber}{12pt}
\settocfeature[toc][4]{spaceafternumber}{12pt}

%Formatting entries
\usepackage{microtype}
\settocfeature[toc][1]{entryhook}{\bfseries} 
\settocfeature[toc][3]{entryhook}{\itshape} 
\settocfeature[toc][4]{entryhook}{}

\renewcommand\addsectiontocentry[2]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{section}{#1}{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#2}}{#2}}%
}
\renewcommand\addsubsectiontocentry[2]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{subsection}{#1}{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#2}}{#2}}%
}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document} 
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{Eins}
\section{Zwei}
\subsection{Zwei}
\section{Drei}
\subsection{Drei}
\subsubsection{Drei}
\section{Vier}
\subsection{Vier}
\subsubsection{Vier}
\paragraph{Vier}
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

---

If you really want to use `tocloft` you can also redefine `\addsectiontocentry` etc.

```
\documentclass[headings=normal, oneside, hidelinks]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text

\usepackage{tocloft}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4} 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

%% Distances between dots
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@dotsep}{0.5}
\makeatother

%% Distances between number and entry
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\l@section}{\vspace{.025\textwidth} \@dottedtocline{1}{20pt}{20pt}}
\renewcommand{\l@subsection}{\@dottedtocline{2}{40pt}{30pt}}
\renewcommand{\l@subsubsection}{\@dottedtocline{3}{70pt}{40pt}}
\renewcommand{\l@paragraph}{\@dottedtocline{4}{110pt}{40pt}}

\usepackage{hyperref} 

\renewcommand\addsectiontocentry[2]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{section}{#1}{\texorpdfstring{\bfseries\MakeUppercase{#2}}{#2}}%
}
\renewcommand\addsubsectiontocentry[2]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{subsection}{#1}{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#2}}{#2}}%
}
\renewcommand\addsubsubsectiontocentry[2]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{subsubsection}{#1}{\texorpdfstring{\itshape#2}{#2}}%
}

\begin{document} 
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{Eins}
\section{Zwei}
\subsection{Zwei}
\section{Drei}
\subsection{Drei}
\subsubsection{Drei}
\section{Vier}
\subsection{Vier}
\subsubsection{Vier}
\paragraph{Vier}
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I will probably use the KOMA script Version as soon as the error message doesn't show up anymore. But for now, this alternative solution works great - thank you for the detailed answer!